# Running pl/sql in Korn Shell(AIX)

Tags: oracle, unix, plsql, ksh, sqlplus

I have a file to execute in Ksh written by someone. It has a set of commands to execute in sqlplus.

It starts with,

```
sqlplus -s $UP <<- END
```

followed by a set of ddl commands such as create,drop,etc.,

When I execute the file in the shell, I get the error in the starting line quoted above.
I understand "-s" starts the sqlplus in silent mode and $UP is the connection string with username/password. But I couldn't make heads or tails of "<<- END" part(Many sites from google says input redirection is "<<" not "<<-"). So I presumed the error must be in that part and removed it from the file.
Now it reads,

```
sqlplus -s $UP
```

But once I execute the file, It waits for input from the shell, instead of reading the rest of the lines from the file. How would I make sqlplus to execute the ddl commands in the rest of the file?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the problem? Does the original script work or not? 

The <<- (and also <<<) is completely legal redirection, named "Here Document" and it means that all following lines should be fed as standard input to the command, until the delimiter (in your case, END) is reached. Have a look into ksh manpage for more detailed explanation.

Comment: @Juraj. It sort of worked partially. It was complaining that it didn't know what "END" means.

Comment: The hyphen in `<<-` allows you to indent the block using leading tabs for readability. The tabs will be stripped so they don't affect the contents of the block. Without the hyphen, leading tabs could be significant depending on the context.

Comment: I found a detailed info about this here: http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here "END" is a block marker and "-" is not required.

For running sqls from a shell script , One simple example is  given below.

```
sqlplus system/manager << ENDOFSQL 

       whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
       select sysdate from dual;
       exit;
ENDOFSQL
```

Thanks,

Rinson KE 
DBA